# <jvm-arg>'s not added to JVM on Resin 4, Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, java, resin

We are migrating from Linux (Ubuntu) to Windows Server 2012R2 (don't ask!) and have encountered a setup problem with Resin:

Installing Resin 4 Pro using the packaged `setup.exe` facility, `resin.exe` is created as a Windows Service just fine. It starts and is able to deploy webapps configured as `<host>`'s in `resin.xml`. But then we have some applications that depend on JVM environment variables. On Linux these were configured in `resin.xml` as well, eg.:

```
<jvm-arg>-Dsome.secret.domain=very.secret.com</jvm-arg>
```

but it appears that these ***simply aren't added to the JVM argument list*** when starting Resin as a service. The structure of our conf file is

```
<cluster id="app-tier">
    <server-multi ... />
    <server-default>
        <jvm-arg>
        ...

    <host>
    ...
```

It is my understanding that this is correct (and it corresponds to our Linux setup).

Trying to start Resin manually using

```
java -jar resin.jar start
```

doesn't change anything (even explicitly adding `-conf resin.xml` with full path). Explicitly adding the JVM args to this statement works, but - couriously - they are then present twice on the watchdog JVM process commandline and four times on the Resin JVM!

Any ideas would be welcome - I'm reaching out to Caucho as well, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many config edits and restarts, it turns out that the **ordering** in the XML config **is significant**.

Thus moving the `<server-multi .../>` below the `<server-default>` section solved the problem:

```
<cluster id="app-tier">
    <server-default>
        <jvm-arg>
        ...

    <server-multi ... />

    <host>
    ...
```

This is confirmed by Alex Rojkov from [Caucho](http://caucho.com/about/team):

> [Yes, order is significant. Configuration is read and executed in a single pass. 
>   Alex](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caucho-resin/XJHhYRQbcXc/KTS98neWHwAJ)

Cheers,